# How to return a value from a stored procedures in a large global CORP SQL Server 13.xxx from MS Access 2007-2016 with VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a DLL created in C# in Visual Studio that can return the good product output from our company production SQL Server.

I have a MS Access database witch I have ADMIN privilege to where I in the frontend have VBA coded a DLL object call with this parameters see **"@ in bold below"** from a stored procedure `Biop_ProductionCountersInUTC` in a Report reader database called `POINTDBReport`.

I'll guess that it is a clone database of a real database for read only purpose.

These are the parameter settings in `Biop_ProductionCountersInUTC` stored procedure:

- `@Equipment` (varchar(255), input, No default) aka '62' in the query below
- `@Counter` (varchar(255), input, No default) aka ''OutputGood' in the query below
- `@Start_time` (datetime, input, No default) aka @FROM in the query below
- `@End_time` (datetime, input, No default) aka @TO in the query below

The stored procedure returns an integer.

The DLL function that is call from VBA in the Access database is functioning very well, but I would like to change the call to the SQL Server from the DLL to a VBA code inside my Access database instead. I'm kind a stock in this VBA code after several hours of Google / Youtube search.

I have no privileges in this SQL Server database to e.g. create a new stored procedures that I can call from a QueryDef method or something alike, only a query-call like the SQL Server Query that is listed below or some type of query pass-though maybe.

Then I execute this query that is copy&paste from the DLL source inside SQL Server Management Studio v18.7.1 as a new query I'll get the 'Output' value as a sum as expected. so this SQL Server query works just fine.

This SQL Server query, and it is the same as in the DLL.

```
DECLARE @FROM AS DATETIME2 
DECLARE @TO AS DATETIME2 

SET @FROM = '2021-01-22 05:00:00' 
SET @TO = '2021-01-22 13:15:00' 

DECLARE @dt AS TABLE([Timestamp] DATETIME, [Value] INT, [Format] INT, [EquipmentCounterID] NVARCHAR(255)) 

INSERT INTO @dt 
EXEC Biop_ProductionCountersInUTC '62','OutputGood', @FROM , @TO 

SELECT 
SUM([Value]) AS 'OUTPUT' 
FROM @dt
```

but then I run this VBA code below in debug mode I'll get an error code 3078 message listed below the code. The error occurs after the SQL connection, when the code hit the "Set recordset", the connection to SQL Server seems to work just fine so fare

This is the VBA code so far:

```
Function GetGoodOutoutFromPoint()
On Error GoTo Errhandler
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim conn As String
Dim lsql As String

lsql = "DECLARE @FROM AS DATETIME2 " & vbNewLine & _
    "DECLARE @TO AS DATETIME2" & _
     vbNewLine & _
    "SET @FROM = '2021-01-22 05:00:00'" & vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & _
    "SET @TO = '2021-01-22 13:15:00'" & vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & _
    "DECLARE @dt AS TABLE([Timestamp] DATETIME, [Value] INT, [Format] INT, [EquipmentCounterID]
 NVARCHAR(255))" & vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & _
    "INSERT INTO @dt" & vbNewLine & _
    "EXEC Biop_ProductionCountersInUTC '62','OutputGood', @FROM , @TO" & vbNewLine & _
    vbNewLine & _
    "SELECT" & vbNewLine & _
    "SUM([Value]) AS 'OUTPUT'" & vbNewLine & _
    "FROM @dt"

conn = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=xxx;Database=POINTDBReport;Uid=xx;Pwd=xxx"
Set db = OpenDatabase("", False, False, conn)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(lsql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges) ' Here occurs the error 3078

'Get the good output data an due something with it.
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

Errhandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error retrieving data from Point SQL Server" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "error code " & 
Err.Number & " - " & "error decriptipon " & Err.Description _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Contact Admin", vbCritical, "Error"
    
 If Err.Number = 3078 Then Set db = Nothing
  End If
End Function
```

'************************************************************************************

This is the error I get:

> Error code 3078 - error description
> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query
> 'DECLARE @FROM AS DATETIME2
> DECLARE @TO AS DATETIME2
> SET @FROM = '2021-01-22 05:00:00'
> SET @TO = '2021-01-22 13:15:00'
>
> DECLARE @dt AS TABLE([Timestamp] DATETIME, [Value] INT, [Format] INT, [EquipmentCounterID] NVARCHAR(255))
>
> INSERT INTO @dt
> EXEC Biop_ProductionCountersInUTC '62','OutputGood', @FROM , @TO
>
> SELECT
> SUM([Value]) AS 'OUTPUT'
> FROM @dt'.
>
> Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.

Is there someone in the community that can figure this out, maybe tweak my VBA code a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Dim strFrom       As String
  Dim strTo         As String
  Dim SumResult     As Currency
  
  strFrom = "'2021-01-22 05:00:00'"
  strTo = "'2021-01-22 13:15:00'"
  
  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPT")
     .SQL = "EXEC MyGetSum" & strFrom & "," & strTo
     SumResult = .OpenRecordset()(0)
  End With
```

Now of course the above assumes that you have a stored procedure saved as MyGetSum.

It would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyGetSum
   @FROM DATETIME2,
   @TO DATETIME2
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE @dt AS TABLE([Timestamp] DATETIME, [Value] INT, [Format] INT, [EquipmentCounterID] NVARCHAR(255)) 

   INSERT INTO @dt 
   EXEC Biop_ProductionCountersInUTC '62','OutputGood', @FROM , @TO 

   SELECT 
   SUM([Value]) AS 'OUTPUT' 
   FROM @dt
END
```

Now, of course it is VERY possible that you do NOT have a saved stored procedure server side, and for some reason (like world poverty), you have to have all of the code, lines that you have as per above?

Ok, then I would create Two pt queries in Access. The first one is our base t-sql + sql code. You grab that, set the values, and then run it in the 2nd pt query. We again do this, since writing all that in-line t-sql in VBA is a real mess (trying to save world poverty here).

So, I would create the first PT query in Access. You can (have to) type in free form text into the query (but in MS-ACCESS SQL view mode).
So you have this:

```
DECLARE @FROM AS DATETIME2 
DECLARE @TO AS DATETIME2 

SET @FROM = '@@FROM'
SET @TO = '@@TO'

DECLARE @dt AS TABLE([Timestamp] DATETIME, [Value] INT, [Format] INT, [EquipmentCounterID] NVARCHAR(255)) 

INSERT INTO @dt 
EXEC Biop_ProductionCountersInUTC '62','OutputGood', @FROM , @TO 

SELECT 
SUM([Value]) AS 'OUTPUT' 
FROM @dt
```

So we place the above in our PT query. We can "think of" this query as our source query.

So, it will look like this in MS-access:

[image]

Ok, we save the above as ptSumS  (we tag a "s" on the end for source).

In fact the above does not really have to be a PT query, but that will prevent the access query editor from messing with the sql text as we have above.

Now, create the 2nd PT query (that is the query we will actually run).

So, now our code looks like this:

```
  Dim strFrom       As String
  Dim strTo         As String
  
  Dim SumResult     As Currency
  Dim strSQL        As String
  
  strSQL = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ptSumS").SQL
  
  Debug.Print strSQL
  
  
  strFrom = "2021-01-22 05:00:00"
  strTo = "2021-01-22 13:15:00"
  
  strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@@FROM", strFrom)
  strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@@TO", strTo)
  
  
  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySum")
     .SQL = strSQL
     SumResult = .OpenRecordset()(0)
  End With
```

So, either way, using a PT query is the way to go.

The first example - calls a existing stored procedure (so if you have the ability to write + create + save that server side stored procedure, then you can call + use + consume it with the first example.

However, if you don't have the ability to save + create a stored procedure, then we use the 2nd approach. I created the T-SQL as a pt query, since trying to write all that garbage in the VBA editor is too much pain - just type in the t-sql you have into that "handy dandy" pt query. We never run that first PT query - but are using it as a place holder for the t-sql code. It also means we can modify that t-sql - and not have to change the VBA code.

So, we replace the two date parameters , and then run the 2nd example. And by using pt-queries, then we eliminate all the need for connection strings in code (again - really messy in code if try and spew connection string code all over the place).

And while I shoved the results into the currency VBA type, we could for example do this:

```
  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySum")
     .SQL = strSQL
  End With
```

Now RIGHT after above - since we setup the t-sql, we can now run a report, or even a simple access query that is BASED on the above pt "qrySum". From Access point of view, that query will work just like ANY other plane jane query. So right after above, we could launch a report based on qrySum
eg:

```
docmd.OpenReport "rptMyReport",acViewPreview.
```

Or we could shove the results into a record set like this:

```
  Dim rst        As DAO.Recordset
  
  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySum")
     .SQL = strSQL
     Set rst = .OpenRecordset()
  End With

  debug.print "sum result = " & rst(0)
```

So you could build up the strSQL in code, and still use the above final code snip, but might as well just type in the whole sql mess into a query, execute a replace on the two values and then shove the resulting sql into that 2nd PT query. We don't modify the first one, since if we "replace" the two date parameters, then after that, how can we know what the last values were - and thus can't use the source query over and over.

However, REGARDLESS, you MUST ADOPT the native 17 or later drivers, since WHEN sql server is using datetime2 (as opposed to datetime), then the standard legacy odbc drivers return datetime2 values as strings - and that is a mess of epic proportions. Same goes for reports and just general use of the data in Access - you REALLY have to ensure that you using the newer native 17 odbc drivers. Or I suppose you can modify the server side table(s) and change the datetime2 columns types to datetime (but that in near all cases is not a practical suggestion as it would mess with existing server side code and queries).

Edit:
Setting up the connection from/inside of Access.

So we have two pass-though queries in Access. The FIRST query as noted is just a place holder for the t-ssql code. We don't need (nor even want) a conneciton string.
To create the first PT query:

[image]

It will now prompt for a table - close that dialog.

So, now click on this:

[image]

Now change the view to SQL view - with this:

[image]

Ok, so now we can paste in our first (source t-sql). That will give us the original screen shot I have in above.

so we have this:

[image]

Save the above - we calling it qrySumS

Now, close that, and create our 2nd query.

Again, PT query, but this time do this:

[image]

So we display the property sheet. This is WHERE we will setup the conneciton string. (as noted, we could do/have/set the connection string in code - but hey, the UI is less work.

So in the property sheet, click on the connection builder:

[image]

This will launch the ODBC connector dialogs - and that is WHERE you can setup + enter the same previous information you shared.

[image]

Select new, and then select the ODBC driver.

AS WARNED - try and select a native 17 driver.

[image]

You CAN try using "SQL Server" from that list (if you don't have native 17 installed). But that can cause issues with datetime2. "sql server" as a odbc driver is built into ALL copies of windows. If you choose native 17, then you have to install the native 17 driver on all workstations that use the access application.

Ok, so work though the dialogs.
[image]

In your case, the server name + sql instance looks to be:

SQLDKBA185

and then user + password
[image]

And DO NOT skip the database selection - often so many do!!!

This one:

[image]

When all is said and done, you wind up back to the original starting point, but with the name of the connection you typed in

[image]

And along the way, there is a "test connection" - do try it.

so, you COULD type in, or even cut+paste in the connection string, but the above connection builder (gee, I use it 10 times a day), should result in this:

[image]

Now, this 2nd query can be left blank, since our VBA code fills it out (copies from the first query - replaces the params. We save and called this qrySum in our example code.

So you can type/paste in the connection string. and you can of course use VBA code, but it makes the most sense to just use the connection builder. Note the syntax is VERY similar to the .net connection - but is often a wee bit different - so that's why I suggested to use the connection builder. (we using ODBC as opposed to .net sql provider - but you can often look at one, and translate - re-type to the format required by Access (ODBC format).

Edit #2
If you can determine that the datetime columns are NOT datetime2, then change the t-sql code to use datetime, and you CAN USE the "sql driver" and thus not have to adopt + install native 17 (or later) odbc drivers on each workstation that is to use this application. So, if you use "sql server", then this should/could work on all workstations WITHOUT having to install the later native 17 drivers. This however IS REQUIRED if the table(s) in question on the server ARE using datetime2 as opposed to datetime columns. Do NOT ignore this advice here - much pain and suffering will result if you don't address the datetime2 vs datetime issue.

Comment: The 2nd example. with using the created PT-queries 'ptSumS' give me the debug.print 'strSQL' query string that I can copy/paste to SQL server query window and test the SQL string, and it works find, but when I run the VBA code it crash when it hit the 'With' statement. an error 3265 "Item not found in the collection" occurs. What about the connection to SQL server, how do I connect, send the 'strSQL' and receive the result. I am now able to create the SQL server query string via the PT query 'ptSumS'  in VBA, but not sent it to the SQL server.

Comment: it is assumed you create BEFORE you run the code two queries in Access. And they are BOTH to be marked and setup as PT queries (pass-though). So qrySum, and qrySumS are to be created by you manually (one time) before the code can work. You of course have to setup the correct coneciton string for those two PT quieres. You can hit-ctrl-g (debug window) and type in ? currentdb.Tabledef("and existing linked table).Connection to see what a valid connection string you need for both of the PT queries. So, those PT queries once setup do have a valid connection to sql  server.

Comment: Actually, you ONLY need a valid connection string for the 2nd PT query qrySum - the first one is a just as noted a place holder to "hold" the sql text - no need to type that code into some messy VBA concatenation mess of a code.

Comment: I have not any linked table in my access DB to the SQL server DB, only a SQL string sent and receive method is possible for me. I have no idea if my connection to SQL server is valid until ether the code crashes or the result is returned. unfortunately my coding skills is not that solid for me to error finding connection issues. I have tried several Access/SQL Server connection method from the internet, and so fare I'm stock. I'll think I'll go back to the DLL solution. That I'm in control of, and that is working so fare. Thanks for the effort @Albert. appreciated a lot.

Comment: Then link one table and you have that valid connection right? Alternative is to write whacks of code vs something so clean, so simple. You note limited coding skills then propose a complex amount of coding as solution? (I'm confused). Even in .net, one works hard limit messy connection string code and use an abstracted approach (else connection code is strewn all over the place). Internet connections for ODBC drivers is vast different issue and direct connections to databases is often not allowed. Is this a web service or ODBC link? You can't use a web service call as a connection from ODBC.

Comment: There is no linked table in access DB to the SQL server DB nor a direct connection at all, at this point. Date is received with this current working code from Access vba 'Dim myObj As Object Set myObj = CreateObject("Pointgateway.NNTool") CurrGoodResult = myObj.getOutputGood(lineNr, CurrStartTime, CurrEndTime) from the DLL"Pointgateway" with a class called NNTool with a procedure named  "getOutputGood" that is created in C#. Inside the "getOutputGood" procedure the Store Procedure query string is called with (lineNr, CurrStartTime, CurrEndTime) variable. my coding skills is in a working proces

Comment: Well, as stated if this is some type of web service call, then you have to make a web service call - you CERTAINLY can't use a PT query and a ODBC connection then can you? (so it begs the question WHY you are attempting to use a connection string that is a web service call as opposed to using a ODBC connection? It don't matter if you don't have a linked table - but WHAT matters is can you HAVE a odbc connection. If you can, then the above clean simple code can save you world poverties and suffering.  So context here is everything. A web service call is VAST different then a odbc connection.

Comment: so this will come down to what does the connection string in that class look like - what software stack is it using? You can certainly do a web service call in VBA, but without a clue as to what kind of connection you are talking about then we are all shooting darts with blindfolds on.  If that connection is a oleDB or a ODBC connection string, then you can use the posted code - you just set the querydef.connection to the connection string (or save + set the connection string property of the PT query when you create it). So this will only work if talking about a valid odbc connection string

Comment: So that c# code will be using 1 of 3 possible providers. oleDB, ODBC, or sqlProvider. Those are the 3 common providers used in .net. As noted, it is possible that the .net code is not use one of these 3 common providers (but, it that code is - then as noted, you can shove in the connection string into that queryDef object in Access. If the .net code is NOT using one of these common providers and this is a web service call then you simply can't use that connection string in VBA - but as noted, it will depend on how the C# code connects to the server (what provider stack it is using).

Comment: The SQL query string in the DLL is listed in my question. The connection sting in C# is "Data Source=SQLDKBA185;Initial Catalog=POInTDBAnalysis;Integrated Security=True"; and the command.ExecuteReader string is this "Data Source = SQLDKBA185; Initial Catalog = POINTDBReport; Persist Security Info=True;User ID = POIntDBReader; Password=xxxxxx"; your fine explanation about connections, is unfortunately a bit Greek to me.

Comment: Oh, hey - that is good! That looks to be a standard conneciton - and NOT a web service call. See my edit - aobut 5 minutes - I'll do some screen shots to show how you setup the connection for the 2nd PT query you make (only 2nd query needs the connection. So looking at the connection - the .net code is using the SQL provider. This means in Access you can setup the connection string too! - see the screen shots I add in the next 5 minutes.

Comment: oK, - SEE my edit to my post - I outline how to setup the connection for the 2nd PT query (we called it qrySum in our example code).

Comment: Okay - I have tried all of your suggestion. The ODBC connection is created with a successful TEST. I've discovered that the Query in SQL server Management studio can handle a Datetime variant instead of DataTime2 So I've create 2 ODBC connection one with "SQL Server" and one with "native 17" no problem so fare. I now have to PT query's. The qrySumS with the SQL and the qrySum with the ODBC connection. Then I run the VBA code the error 3325 pop's when the code hit the Set rst = .OpenRecordset() in with statement. The result from 
 ?CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySum").SQL in immediate window is

Comment: tested in a Query in SQL server Management studio and with output result "82944" but with VBA code it breaks. Her is the VBA code

Comment: Function GetGoodOutoutFromPoint()
On Error GoTo Errhandler

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strFrom       As String
Dim strTo         As String
Dim SumResult     As Double
Dim strSQL        As String
  
  strSQL = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySumS").SQL
  strFrom = "2021-01-22 05:00:00"
  strTo = "2021-01-22 13:15:00"
  strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@@FROM", strFrom)
  strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@@TO", strTo)

  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qrySum")
     .SQL = strSQL
     Set rst = .OpenRecordset()
    
  End With

Comment: Debug.Print "sum result = " & rst(0)

Set rst = Nothing

Exit Function
Errhandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error retrieving data from Point SQL Server" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "error code " & Err.Number & " - " & "error decriptipon " & Err.Description _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Contact Admin", vbCritical, "Error"
    
End If
End Function

Comment: After you run the code - try opening the qrySum to look at the code. And in fact, while looking at qrySum AFTER your code runs or even fails. Try running the store proc qrySum while looking at it. Does it run and does it return any values?

Comment: In fact, take a cut + paste of WHAT eventually would up in qrySum, and paste it into the sql studio (ssms) and what do you get?

Comment: I have already tried the cut + paste, see the (output result "82944") comment above. When running the qrySum PT-query from Access give the same “not return any Records” error. It seems to me that the connection is working as it supposed to, but some how the SQL server interpretation of the SQL sting sent via the PT-query is failing, or the SQL server don’t allow connection back with the result. As mention earlier is it a very restricted SQL Server, my access credentials to the server is look only so. Thank for you explanation. I have learn a lot about Accesss connection and PT-queries

Comment: And when you try and paste and run that same t-sql from SSMS? What happens? All you doing here is sending raw t-sql to sql server. So, after you run the code, and it fails, open up the 2nd PT query. Does the syntax look ok? And of course then cut + paste of that 2nd query (that had the params replaced in VBA).  Paste that into SSMS. I mean, the net code or ANY OTHER code CAN NOT work if this don't work (the .net code works no different). So on  your machine, connect with ssms - paste in that that resulting t-sql - does it work? This takes what - 2 whole minutes of your life to check?

Comment: if the .net routine CAN work, then so can this code - it does not really do anything different here. All we are doing is sending raw sql to sql server. As noted, cut + paste in the results of the 2nd PT query into SSMS studio and run it. Does it run? Does the syntax look ok? Does the syntax pass, or does the code/query (when using SSMS) work? If you can't run the code from SSMS running on your same computer, then the .net code can't work, the ms-access code can't work, and from SSMS it can't work. On the other hand, if one can work, then they ALL WILL work.